# Key prop in <List />

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making to do list

I input key prop but console keep show me error

Should I put in keys into button?

```
<Container>
  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Input
      value={inputTerm}
      onChange={updateTerm}
      type="text"
      placeholder="What you gonna do today?"
    />
  </Form>
  <Item>
    {list.map((list, index) => {
      return (
        <>
          <List key={index}>
            {list}
            <Button id={index} onClick={handleDelete}>
              <span>X</span>
            </Button>
          </List>
        </>
      );
    })}
  </Item>
</Container>
```

Comment: Please post the original code as text here rather than posting the images of code.

Comment: You should not be wrapping your list with blank tags (react fragment)`<>`

Comment: What error are you getting? Reason for why you shouldn't post images of your code: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá Its not wrong but here its not required. Also, using `index` as key is a bad idea. You can have miltiple `<Item>` with `<List>` and they will have same index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is key works on whole block(it can be anything). So it is expecting key at fragment part.

Either you can do this:

```
<React.Fragment key={your key}>
...
</React.Fragment>
```

or

```
<List key={index}>
</List>
//remove your fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing a `.map` in React JSX,

it is expecting immediately-nested element to have a key props.

Since you are using `React.Fragment` shorthand `<>`, you cannot pass the key props.

Therefore, you will have to remove it and just use

```
<List key={index>...</List>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `<>` inside your `return()` block. Its a shorthand for `<Fragment>` as you know. However if you want to use fragment for some reason , then key can be added like `<Fragment key={key}>`.

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

.........

<Container>
  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Input
      value={inputTerm}
      onChange={updateTerm}
      type="text"
      placeholder="What you gonna do today?"
    />
  </Form>
  <Item>
    {list.map((list, key) => {
      return (
        <Fragment key={key}>
          <List key={index}>
            {list}
            <Button onClick={handleDelete}>
              <span>X</span>
            </Button>
          </List>
        </>
      );
    })}
  </Item>
</Container>
```

You may also use `React.Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep `<List>` as outer most component in map function, so in this way your console error will resolved....

```
{list.map((list, index) => {
  return (
      <List key={index}>
        {list}
        <Button id={index} onClick={handleDelete}>
          <span>X</span>
        </Button>
      </List>
  );
})}
```